# R: Looping through all files in the directory, applying the column replacement command

Tags: r, loops, lapply

So I have a a directory of .txt files. Each contains columns representing features of some measurement. For the files in the same directory, I want to replace the content of one column named `treatmentsum` to `3S_TNFaCHx_cluster1_333nM+0.1ug/ml_none`. (I will replace the same column with different names in different folders, and yes I know this name is utterly annoying, trust me there are much worse names)

So I thought, replacing the column in a dataframe is easy, I just open directory then do below:

```
df <- read.table(x, header=TRUE)
df$treatmentsum <- c("3S_TNFaCHx_cluster1_333nM+0.1ug/ml_none")
```

Next, I just need to make this a function and `lapply` it to all files in the directory and make sure the new files are deposited in a new folder.

The full code did not work:

```
#set up directories
directory <- "C:/Users/XXX"
outdirectory <- "C:/Users/XXX/replaced"

#find all .txt files in the directory
files <- list.files(path=directory, pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

lapply(files, function(x) {
    df <- read.table(x, header=TRUE)
    df$treatmentsum <- c("the new stupid name thanks to pharma")
    out <- function(df)
    # write to file
    write.table(out, outdirectory, sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
})
```

warning message that I got:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 1 did not have 744 elements

Comment: One glaring issue is this `out <- function(df)` which returns nothing. Simply pass `df` into `write.table`.

Comment: Thank you Parfait for editing. I deleted out <- function(df) and put write.table(df, outdirectory, sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE). Same error message...

Comment: You should be giving the output path a physical file not folder.

Comment: I didn't quite get it, sorry noob here. you mean write.table(df, XXX, sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE). The XXX needs to be a file? what files shall I put it there?

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating the folder structure and tested out the following code. Seems to work.

```
source_folder <- "Folder1"
destination_folder <- "Folder2"

files <- list.files(path = source_folder, pattern = "*.txt", 
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

lapply(files, function(x) {
  df <- read.table(x, header=TRUE)
  df$Col2 <- c("the new stupid name thanks to pharma")
  write.table(df, paste0(destination_folder,"/", basename(x)), sep="\t", 
              quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thank you Vishal, but I still got the same error message on the line 1 did not have 744 elements

Comment: Hi Vishal, very interestingly, the code runs when added fill=T. however the returning tables are filled with lots exta columns of NA, and half of the headers are messed up. I changed read.table to read.csv, and it fixed that. The only problem is in the end of the table, I now have an extra column of NA

Comment: @Parfait Hi Parfait,(omg you can use @ here!) are you referring to the "messed up NAs"? I had similar responses from others regarding to the extra column of NA in the end of the data when using  read.csv. I got the data from previous people from the lab, and by reading the .txt file with notepad, it seems the delimiter is tab or space.  The instrument that output the file only provides .txt format, I hope one day they can just generate csv files.

Comment: @Parfait. I tried using read.delim(), the output files still have the extra column of NA

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the help. the row,names = 1 was not allowed in read.delim.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the help. the row,names = 1 was not allowed in read.delim. I tried to upload a screenshot of the data, stack wont let me but provided a link.